CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQLite ends up as string literal
I have a following query in SQLite:
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` text PRIMARY KEY,
    `created_at` text DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

For some reason, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is treated as a string literal and creating new rows would insert a "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" instead of a calculated timestamp.
I encountered this issue in Turso and tried different combinations like (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) so I though it might be the issue of their variation of SQLite - libsql but it turns out that I encountered this problem on another environment too. You should be able to reproduce this behaviour in https://sqliteonline.com/.
In fact, there's more to that because I couldn't get functions like datetime() or strftime() to work either.
Any idea what could be the problem here?

What version of SQLite does the system run?

https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_datetime_funcs could explain the missing functions,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP itself exists since 2005-01-21 (3.1.0 ALPHA)

I've encountered a similar issue, where the weirdest part was that for my older columns, the timestamp was generated correctly (as number), and only for new columns it returned a string. I'm also not sure how the RDBMS allowed inserting string into integer column.
As a workaround, I've applied migration changing all "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" into "(unixepoch())" as described in Drizzle ORM docs:

https://orm.drizzle.team/learn/guides/timestamp-default-value#sqlite

